# Set day of year DateTime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to set the day of year for a DateTime, I am getting the day of year from a past date say '5/7/2000" that day is 128, I now want to set another DateTime with that day 128 so I can get the day of that date this year which would be Monday. Can you help me?

Here is the code I am trying, I have the date bound in a listbox and I am tapping it to get the selected date

```
string selectedTap = "";
int dayOfYear;
DateTime dayOfThisYear;
var selected = listBoxItem.SelectedValue as Ages;
selectedTap = selected.DOB;
dayOfYear = (DateTime.Parse(selectedTap, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DayOfYear);
//dayOfThisYear.DayOfYear = dayOfYear;    //Need to set this date

MessageBox.Show(selectedTap + dayOfYear);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new DateTime for the current year, then add the appropriate number of days:

```
dayOfThisYear = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, 1, 1).AddDays(dayOfYear - 1);
```

Comment: But remember: If the selected year is a leap year, `dayOfYear` might be `366`. If additionally the year "now" is **not** a leap year, then you will come to January 1 of the next year.

Comment: Thanks, @JeppeStigNielsen great thanks I was able to test for leap year with `DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)`.

Answer (score 6):

Get 1/1/(whatever year).AddDays(day of year - 1)